# Puzzling function composition

Tags: haskell, function-composition

How can I make sense of function composition in the following expression?

```
map . foldr (.) id :: [b -> b] -> [b] -> [b]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
f :: [a->a] -> a -> a
f = foldr (.) id
```

This takes list of functions and compose them together

for example

```
foldr (.) id [(+1),(+2)] == ((+1) . ((+2) . id)) == (+3)
```

Function application has higest fixity and map is made last

```
map . foldr (.) id == \x -> map ( foldr (.) id x )
```

It maps `foldr (.) id` over list (2nd argument) after first argument (list of functions) is applied